# How can I access the overridden properties of a .NET API object in IronPython?

Tags: .net, ironpython, autodesk, revit

I am using IronPython to create a shell for a plugin API to Autodesk Revit Architecture 2010 to speed up learning their API.

One of the classes the API provides is `Autodesk.Revit.Elements.Room`, derived from `Autodesk.Revit.Element`.

I would really love to read `Room.Name`, but this goes *Boom!* on me as `Room` has overridden `Element`s `Name` property like so:

```
public override string Name { set; }
```

This of course hides the getter...

Given an object of type `Room`, how can I access the base classes getter?

I have tried

```
room.base.Name
```

But it seems that .NET-derived classes do not have a base property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the way to specify exactly on which interface / class you want to invoke the getter:

Given an `Autodesk.Revit.Elements.Room` object `room`, the 'Name' property in its base class can be called with

```
Autodesk.Revit.Element.Name.__get__(room)
```

or

```
Autodesk.Revit.Element.Name.GetValue(room)
```