# Get Name of WallType in PyRevit

Tags: python, pyrevit

How do I get the `Name` of a `WallType` in PyRevit? I can get to `FamilyName`, but it's not what I want, I want the exact name of the wall (e.g., '300mm concrete'). The code I use:

```
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
walls  = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).\
         WhereElementIsElementType().ToElements()

for wall in walls:
    print(wall.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the [`Name`](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/1198805b-fdbf-54bf-64d3-90dbd01b4c5f.htm) from a [`WallType`](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/aa685433-b426-5e4f-bee1-e3487bb59518.htm) because it inherits from [`ElementType`](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/ffb18296-0448-559c-580c-7857cbcdc094.htm) and this class does not include a getter for [`Name`](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/1198805b-fdbf-54bf-64d3-90dbd01b4c5f.htm).

What you could do to retrieve the name is accessing the overriden properties of the object as seen [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310819/how-can-i-access-the-overridden-properties-of-a-net-api-object-in-ironpython).

Which you can easily adapt to your code as:

```py
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
walls  = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).\
         WhereElementIsElementType().ToElements()

for wall in walls:
    print(Element.Name.GetValue(wall))
```

Comment: But ElementType inherits from `Element` which, in turn, has a <a href='https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/e372092e-ff47-71c2-1272-50ab08e5a41d.htm'>`Name`</a>